# Many nouns that can sometimes be countable and others uncountable

Tags: word-usage, uncountable-nouns

I really have a problem using such as these following nouns 
, disagreement, balance and alteration...etc . Because sometimes they can be considered countable and othertime uncountable. So how can i know if I should use it as countable or uncountable?... please help me !

Comment: Use a [dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/balance_1?q=balance)?

Comment: A dictionary wouldn't help me enough cuz when i write about something how would i know if i should usethe word in a uncountable form or countable ? @laurel

Comment: Context is the guide for native speakers. Use the **[edit]** link to add an example in which you are confused about whether to treat a word as countable or uncountable; then we may be able to help. ("cuz", "wanna", "gotta", etc. are useful in text messaging, or among friends, but they may not be appropriate elsewhere.)

Comment: Thank u for ur reply and this good note, what kind of books do you highly recommend to improve my language ?

Comment: Please add an example to your question; it may be closed unless you provide an example, and tell us what research you have done on your own. ("Because sometimes can be considered countable and othertime uncountable..." is a clause without a subject; that is why it was edited to say "Because sometimes they can be considered countable and other time uncountable." Also, we end English sentences with a period, not with a comma.)

Comment: You are totally right but before ( so ) i put a comma because it is a cordinating conjunction and i should put a comma before.

Comment: As already commented, you need to add some example sentences using the words in question. Then you can consider the countability.

Comment: The acid test is whether it can combine with the cardinal numbers, "one, two, three, etc.," If it can't in the NP in which it occurs, then it's not a count noun in that particular NP.

Answer (score 1):

You might helpful my answer to this previous question:  [Why do we say "I love cake" but "I love cars"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/129724/why-do-we-say-i-love-cake-but-i-love-cars)

English speakers tend to use the *uncountable* form to refer to the *generic* or *conceptual* noun, and the *countable* to refer to *specific*, *quantifiable* instances:

> I would prefer to avoid *disagreement*.
>
> The two countries have had many *disagreements* over the years, but never an open war.

As others have pointed out, this varies with context and idiom, and it would be impossible to list all the variations.  A good example is "love", which is mostly used as a generic noun:

> She has never known *love*.

But it can be countable when talking about a specific instance (or set of instances).

> She was *the love* of his life.

However, this can get confusing when mixing countable instances with the generic concept:

> In his old age he loved to talk about the many women with whom he found *love*.