# different "culture" or different "cultures"

Tags: uncountable-nouns

I believe this is simple, yet crucial and time-worthy to know amongst ELLs.

> As a traveler, I've experienced **different culture/cultures** across the world.

First off, **culture** is an *uncountable noun*.

Every time I'm going to use this word "culture", I've always been unsure whether it should be *just* "culture" (singular), or "cultures" (plural).

Come to think of it, you cannot count "culture", and grammar books say it too.

So, in the sentence above, can you say **different culture** specifically?

Confusion and annoyance:

- **Different fruit/fruits?**
- **Different vegetable/vegetables**

*Please note that I've included "**different**" before a noun, which should usually be followed by a **plural noun** (for example "different books", "different computers").*

Comment: Many nouns are both countable and uncountable, depending on the context – _culture_ would be one of them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your grammar book is, unfortunately, incorrect.  Culture is both *countable* and *uncountable*, depending on which definition you mean:

> [**culture**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/culture) (n):
>
> 1. [mass noun] The arts and other manifestations of human intellectual achievement regarded collectively
> 2. [count noun] The ideas, customs, and social behaviour of a particular people or society.

Examples:

> Different countries have different **cultures**.
>
> Everyone loves living in that city, but they all complain about the lack of **culture**.

It is possible to talk about "different culture" in the abstract sense of the word:

> Everyone says the East Coast of the United States has a very **different culture** from the West Coast.

Various other nouns (like *fruit*) also have the quality of being *uncountable* in the abstract, while *countable* in the concrete.

> My doctor says I should eat more **fruit** every day.
>
> My favorite **fruits** are kiwi, mango, and guava.

*Vegetable* is slightly different, since the singular can be an adjective

> The entire structure seems to be covered in a dense layer of **vegetable** matter.

The plural is always a noun referring to particular types of vegetables:

> Broccoli, brussels sprouts, cabbage, and kale are different **vegetables** that nevertheless all belong to same species.

Comment: Thx very much. As I've gone over this answer, is it correct to say that the difference between *uncountable* noun and *countable* noun is the **"concrete or abstract"** sense of them? Will it be a good foundation when thinking which one to use in a sentence? Or should I say, **absolutely I should...**

Comment: @JohnArvin  I don't know if it's that simple.  Is "fruit" abstract or concrete?  It is a thing, even when talking about it in a general way.  And then you have the various uncountable things like *water* or *juice*, both of which are measured by quantity, not number.  Or [cake](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/129724/why-do-we-say-i-love-cake-but-i-love-cars/129728#129728) as in *"I love cake"* vs. *"I'd love a cake"*

Answer (score 3):

Culture, in this context, is *not* an uncountable noun. "I've experienced different culture" is not correct, although you could say something like "he comes from a different culture."

Similarly, you cannot use fruit/vegetable like that:

- Five **different vegetables** were served with dinner. (Note that this almost always means *five different types* of vegetables: carrots, spinach, etc.)
- I would have preferred a **different vegetable** than the one I was served.

Fruit is a little weird, since you generally say "I ate fruit for breakfast," (it's uncountable in this usage), but you could not say "I ate vegetable" -- it's always either "I ate a vegetable" or "I ate vegetables."

But fruit would still be used as above, when modified by *different:*

- Five **different fruits** were served at breakfast (i.e., five different types of fruit).
- I would have preferred to eat a **different fruit** than the durian I was served.

Comment: It's not incorrect, just less common. If you saw an art gallery in Paris, jazz in New Orleans and opera in Fiji, you'd have experienced different culture across the world.

Answer (score 1):

When traveling, I hesitate to identify one distinct culture. I err on the side of caution with diverse groups and broadly refer to "cultures."

Here is a good example from Louisiana Folklife:

> "A complex blend of French, Spanish, German, African, Irish, and Native American influences created a unique regional culture. Yet, when one looks closer, one becomes aware of local variations: in spite of its deep French roots, South Louisiana is not a monolithic, homogeneous Francophonic culture."

Therefore after visiting, you may have experienced a variety of cultures.

Good luck, 
G.