# How many beans vs How much beans?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

When talking about beans, lentils or chickpeas should they be considered as countable or uncountable?

Would a person normally say "How many beans should I cook?" or "how much beans should I cook?" Especially if the expected answer is measured in weight (EG: 200 grams) and not in actual numbers of beans.

Comment: They would ask "How many?", but expect an answer by volume (or possibly weight), not to be told the exact number of beans to cook!

Comment: I agree with @KateBunting on this, but without knowing exactly *why* it's right. Grammatically [syntactically?] it doesn't make a lot of sense, but you'd never ask "How much beans?" Even though you expect the answer to be in cups or grammes, the answer will never be 432.

Comment: I'd ask *How **much** beans do you want?* if I had no choice. But it's not much better than *How **many...,*** so I might just sidestep the issue with something uncontentious like *Do you want **lots of** beans?* Or *How many **spoonfuls** of beans?* (spare me from ***spoonsful**!* :)

Comment: @KateBunting - hmmm . . .  not sure. As a keen amatuer cook, if I were unsure I would probably ask "how many grams of beans should I cook" or "how many cans of beans".  To ask "How many beans" could be the cue for a sarcastic response - "242 should be fine".

Comment: "How much" is correct. If someone asked me how **many** beans I wanted, I would consider it a mistake, and answer with a precise number like "24" to point out the question was silly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we say "I love cake" but "I love cars"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/129724/why-do-we-say-i-love-cake-but-i-love-cars)

Answer (score 0):

In most situations, they would be uncountable. You would ask "how many beans" only when you truly expect the answer to be a number of beans rather than a measurement. For instance, someone might put some beans in a jar and hold a contest to guess "how many" beans are in the jar.

Meanwhile, you could ask "how many" about countable *units of measurement*.

"Cook some beans."

"How many grams?"

In the comments some have suggested that "How much beans do you want" sounds odd. I think that's just because of the situation. I think "How much beans should I cook" sounds perfectly fine, because one expects a detailed answer to the vague question (100 grams, or 1.5 kg, or half a liter). Serving someone and asking "how much beans do you want" is odd simply because it's hard to answer. "Uh... this much?"

Comment: "How much beans do you want?" - "Three ladles." Is this not how you normally measure gruelly or granular food - by the utensil you're serving it with?